# php double extension vulnerability

Tags: php, security

I am trying to learn more about file upload in PHP. I faced with a problem.
I read some articles and watch some videos that hacker can attack with double extension however you check the file extension. like

> something.php.jpg

How can it be prevented? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The extension isn't relevant unless you make it relevant. When a file upload is available in your PHP,  it doesn't have an extension. It's still true that file uploads come from the user, and as with all user provided data should be treated sceptically and should never be executed directly.

Comment: for which platform? please specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also been interested in this question. I have tested a double extension like something.php.jpg on multiple servers and I am starting to believe that it is not a real security vulnerability unless there is something else set incorrectly on the server. On all the Apache servers I tested it on it did not execute the php code in the file.

Most discussions on php upload vulnerabilities quote from this website: https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/ where the author first quotes from: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext where it says:

> Files can have more than one extension; the order of the extensions is normally irrelevant. For example, if the file welcome.html.fr maps onto content type text/html and language French then the file welcome.fr.html will map onto exactly the same information. If more than one extension is given that maps onto the same type of metadata, then the one to the right will be used, except for languages and content encodings. For example, if .gif maps to the media-type image/gif and .html maps to the media-type text/html, then the file welcome.gif.html will be associated with the media-type text/html.

Then the author of https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/ says:

> Therefore, a file named filename.php.123, will be interpreted as a PHP file by Apache HTTP Server, and it will be executed. This of course, will only work if the last extension (in this case .123), is not specified in the list of MIME-types known to the web server...If AddHandler directive is used, all filenames containing the .php extension ( .php, .php.jpg) will be executed as a PHP script.

It seems like this is reverse as to what the Apache docs stated. Please correct me if I am missing something. The Apache docs stated, "welcome.gif.html will be associated with the media-type text/html", therefore I would assume that something.php.jpg would be associated with media-type image/jpeg.

Then the author of the article states that the vulnerability arises if the apache configuation file has this line:

> AddHandler php5-script .php

I tried that line as well and the file still did not execute as php. But most AddHandler lines I have seen in the past 10 years are more like this:

> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .php

So is the above line not vulnerable to the double extension vulnerability? Or is there particular versions of php or Apache that are vulnerable and certain versions of php or Apache that are not vulnerable?

Of course, I believe that the uploaded file should still have the mime type checked, but I have read that the mime type can be spoofed as well.

Answer (score -1):

User uploads are problematic. There are things you can do to mitigate the risk. For instance, if you intend to allow only image uploads, then you can use the inbuilt [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)() function to ensure that the user is actually uploading a valid image file.

```
//  Let's assume that the name attribute of the file input field you have used is "myfile"

$tempFile =  $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];  // path of the temp file created by PHP during upload
switch(mime_content_type($tempFile)) { 

 case "image/jpeg":
 // your actions go here...

    }
}
else {
    echo "This is not a valid image file";
}
```

Further reading: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form

Comment: as https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/ mentioned here. It is told that this method is not that safe.

Comment: You can also use mime_content_type(). I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Progrock ya, fixed.

Comment: Mime types are client dependent! Can be changed the same way filenames are!